# Holder potentials over time-one map of Anosov flow

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

I have two quick questions that I've been having a hard time finding an answer to. Let $f^{t}: M \rightarrow M$ be a transitive Anosov flow on a closed Riemannian manifold $M$.

(1) Let $\varphi: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Holder continuous function. Is $\varphi$ cohomologous to a function $\psi$ on $M$ with $\psi(x) = \int_{0}^{1}\zeta(f^{s}x)ds$ for a Holder function $\zeta$?

(2) The motivation for part (1): suppose that $\mu_{\varphi}$ is an equilibrium state for the time-one map $f^{1}$ with respect to $\varphi$. Is $\mu_{\varphi}$ the equilibrium state of some potential $\zeta$ for the full flow $f^{t}$?

So to summarize, does working over the time-one map of an Anosov flow change anything when one looks at equilibrium states or potentials? I want to work with a potential over $f^{1}$ that's not obviously obtained by integrating along orbits.

Comment: It strikes me as a little unlikely that every $C^\alpha$ function should be cohomologous to a function which is $C^{1+\alpha}$ in the flow direction, and I wonder if a Baire category argument might be found to show that this cannot be the case.

Comment: Oh of course, I should clarify the picture I have in my head: I do want to assume in advance that $\varphi$ is $C^{1+\alpha}$ in the flow direction.  I agree that without that hypothesis the claim seems unlikely.

Comment: Maybe replace transitivity by topological mixing, or assume the ergodicity of $f^1$. Otherwise, one may get a counterexample [to (1)] from suspension flow of an Anosov diffeomorphism.